# ATtiny85, timer 1B does not work if COM1A1|COM1A0==0

Tags: avr, timer

I read the datasheet, and checked http://www.avrfreaks.net forum, but I cannot understand why on an [ATtiny85](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2586-AVR-8-bit-Microcontroller-ATtiny25-ATtiny45-ATtiny85_Datasheet.pdf):

```
int main()
{ 
    TCCR1|=_BV(CS10); 
    GTCCR|=_BV(PWM1B); 
    GTCCR|=_BV(COM1B1)|_BV(COM1B0);    
    DDRB|=_BV(PB4);  
    OCR1B=0x80; 
    while(1){} 
}
```

Does not work until I add:

```
 TCCR1|=_BV(COM1A0);
```

Which I guess I should not need if I want to use only timer 1B.

Comment: We need more information. It looks like you're using the timer to generate a PWM pulsechain. Is this correct? What behaviour are you expecting, and what are you getting? "Does not work" really does not tell us much of anything useful.

Comment: Please add the disassmbly listing `avr-objdump -C -d <yourprogram>.elf` and what are your installed versions of `gcc-avr` and `avr-libc`?

Comment: First of all, there is no “timer 1B”, there just is a timer 1, which gets compared against multiple registers. Second, in PWM mode, you need to set `OCR1C`.

Comment: I usually go for the register descriptions, but they are not very clear in this case. However, according to section 12.2.2 in the attiny85 datasheet, OCR1C is TOP and OCR1A/B is the duty. Worked for me using OC1A.